# При попытке из иcходников поставить Mysql 5.6 на Ubuntu 20.04 выдаёт ошибку

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Выдаётся ошибка при попытка установки MySQL 5.6 из Unutu 20.04 по официальной инструкции:
Команда cmake ..

-- ZSTD_LIBRARY /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1
CMake Error at cmake/lz4.cmake:50 (MESSAGE):
Cannot find system lz4 libraries.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:516 (MYSQL_CHECK_LZ4)

P.S Файл /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 Есть
PP.S Библиотека lz4 установлена.

Comment: Это не та библиотека, установить нужно именно lz4

Comment: Она установлена

Comment: Выполните команду `whereis libz4`

Comment: whereis libz4
libz4:
root@vps:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# apt install libz4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libz4

Comment: ... `apt install libz-dev`

Comment: apt install libz-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' instead of 'libz-dev'
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить файл поиска lz4 https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell/blob/master/cmake/lz4.cmake

Comment: -- Library mysqlserver depends on OSLIBS -lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1;m;rt;atomic;crypt;dl;-lrt;-ldl
CMake Deprecation Warning at scripts/CMakeLists.txt:281 (CMAKE_POLICY):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0007 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

Comment: Так, ради интереса: а зачем из исходников?

Comment: Хочу прикрутить Rocksdb